# Original source for a well-known result of convergence in measure and almost everywhere

Tags: measure-theory, real-analysis

A well-known result in measure theory states that given a sequence $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of measurable functions from a $\sigma$-finite measure space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ then the sequence $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ convergences in measure to a function $f$ if and only *every* subsequence $(f_{n_m})_{m=1}^\infty$ has a subsequence $(f_{n_{m_p}})_{p=1}^\infty$ which converges to $f$ almost everywhere.

> By whom and where was this theorem originally proved?

Comment: $(1_{(n,\infty)})_{n=1}^\infty$ is the standard counterexample for the result you state.

Answer (score 2):

That every sequence congerging in measure has an almust surely congerging subsequence was apparently first shown by Riesz in 1909 in "Sur les suites de fonctions mesurables". I don't know about the other direction, but Frechet is a likely culprit. [Source](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpubs.ub.ro%2Fdwnl.php%3Fid%3DSSRSMI200902V19S01A0018&ei=_SM4UuHUOIy4hAeCsoDIDg&usg=AFQjCNFxnag6QDddei7hUSumbU1-SzBrOQ&bvm=bv.52164340,d.ZG4)

Comment: Since the other direction is a consequence of the metrizability of the space of real-valued measurable functions on $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$, one may look for whom introduced a distance on that space (Frechét?).